# canvas isPointInPath does not work with ctx.drawImage()

Tags: html, canvas, drawimage

1. I suppose this doesn't work because canvas is drawing a bitmap of a vector (and a bitmap is not a path).
2. Even if it did work, the bitmap is likely always has a rectangular permitter.

Is there any way to leverage something like `isPointInPath` when using `drawImage`?

example:

- The top canvas is drawn using `drawImage` and `isPointInPath` does not work.
- The bottom canvas is drawn using `arc` and `isPointInPath` works.

[a link to my proof](http://jsfiddle.net/4a9mK/)

** EDIT **

I draw a circle on one canvas, and use `isPointInPath` to see if the mouse pointer is inside the circle (bottom canvas in my example).
I also "copy" the bottom canvas to the top canvas using `drawImage`. Notice that `isPointInPath` will not work on the top canvas (most likely due to reasons I mentioned above). Is there a work-around I can use for this that will work for ANY kind of path (or bitmap)?

Comment: The question cannot be understood. You want to test whether a certain pixel in an image is transparent?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa I added an edit to my question. Hopefully my addition clarifies the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A canvas context has this hidden thing called the current path. `ctx.beginPath`, `ctx.lineTo` etc create this path.

When you call `ctx.stroke()` or `ctx.fill()` the canvas strokes or fills that path.

Even after it is stroked or filled, the path is still present in the context.

This path is the **only** thing that `isPointInPath` tests.

If you want to test if something is in an image you have drawn or a rectangle that was drawn with `ctx.fillRect()`, that is not possible using built in methods.

Typically you'd want to use a is-point-in-rectangle function that you write yourself (or get from someone else).

If you're looking for how to do pixel-perfect (instead of just the image rectangle) hit detection for an image there are various methods of doing that discussed here: [Pixel perfect 2D mouse picking with Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578545/pixel-perfect-2d-mouse-picking-with-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

You could try reimplementing `ctx.drawImage()` to always draw a box behind the image itself, like so ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/49GNr/)):

```
ctx.customDrawImage = function(image, x, y){
    this.drawImage(image, x, y);
    this.rect(x, y, image.width, image.height);
}
var img1 = new Image();
img1.onload = function(){
var x = y = 0;
ctx.drawImage(img1, x, y);
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(x + 1, y + 1));

x = 1.25 * img1.width;
ctx.customDrawImage(img1, x, y);
console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(x + 1, y + 1));
```

Note: you might get side effects like the rectangle appearing over the image, or bleeding through from behind if you are not careful.

Comment: You could avoid that bleeding by not stroke()ing or fill()ing the path. Just test it and throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

To me, isPointInPath failed after canvas was moved. So, I used:

`mouseClientX -= gCanvasElement.offsetLeft;
mouseclientY -= gCanvasElement.offsetTop;`

Answer (score 0):

I had some more challenges, because my canvas element could be rescaled. So first when I draw the figures, in my case arc, I save them in an array together with a name and draw them:

```
      if (this.coInit == false)
      {
        let co = new TempCO ();
        co.name= sensor.Name;
        co.path = new Path2D();
        co.path.arc(c.X, c.Y, this.radius,  0, 2 * Math.PI);
        this.coWithPath.push(co);
      }
      let coWP = this.coWithPath.find(c=>c.name == sensor.Name);
      this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
      this.ctx.fill(coWP.path);
```

Then in the mouse event, I loop over the items and check if the click event is in a path. But I also need to rescale the mouse coordinates according to the resized canvas:

```
getCursorPosition(event) {
  const rect = this.ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = ((event.clientX - rect.left ) / rect.width) * this.canvasWidth;
  const y = ((event.clientY - rect.top) / rect.height) * this.canvasHeight;
  this.coWithPath.forEach(c=>{

    if (this.ctx.isPointInPath(c.path, x, y))
    {
      console.log("arc is hit", c);
      //Switch light
    }
  });
}
```

So I get the current size of the canvas and rescale the point to the original size. Now it works!

This is how the TempCO looks like:

```
export class TempCO
{
  path : Path2D;
  name : string;
}
```